# How to specify which .NET framework to use at runtime

Tags: c#, .net-3.5, .net-4.5

I have an application which currently runs in the `.NET 3.5` framework.  However, in the event that SharePoint 2013 is installed, the application needs to load up a different set of dlls that will utilize `.NET 4.0 and/or 4.5`.  From my understanding, creating a 'bootstrapper' would handle the event.

Going around and evaluating the SharePoint version will be easy enough, but how do I set up the logic for which set of dlls to load for the application?  I am currently working off of the assumption that it will deal with dynamically loading the dlls, but I am unsure as to the best method to approach this.

What would be the best way to dynamically choose between .NET versions?

Some links I have already looked into include: [Specifying the location of .Net configuration files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4150383/specifying-the-location-of-net-configuration-files)  and [MSBuild, conditional NET runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14979802/msbuild-conditional-net-runtime)  and [Conditional Compilation and Framework Targets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2923210/c-sharp-conditional-compilation-and-framework-targets).  But I was not able to glean a lot of useful information from them.  Currently I am exploring along the line of this question: [DllImport vs LoadLibrary, What is the best way?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/548382/dllimport-vs-loadlibrary-what-is-the-best-way)

Comment: There is no problem using a .NET2/3.5 assembly in a .NET4 application.

Answer (score 0):

You can try setting [supportedRuntime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w4atty68.aspx) in your App.config to choose the .Net version.

Something like:

```
<configuration>
   <startup>
      <supportedRuntime version="v4.0"/>
   </startup>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Piggybacking off of your suggestion, I also found a similar link http://www.davidmoore.info/2010/12/17/running-net-2-runtime-applications-under-the-net-4-runtime/ which I will be looking into to see if I get the expected behavior